# refresh and re-populate select box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I populate my select box using php code below, my problem now is that i have my reference form which add new items to this select box. what I want is when I add new drawer item from my reference, i want to refresh this select box only not affecting the whole page. I read about ajax/jquery/js solution, but i don't know how to integrate it.

```
<td>Drawer</td>
        <td>
            <select name="municipality" class="country" style="width: 200px;">
              <option selected="selected"></option>
              <?php
                    $sql=mysql_query("select idDrawer,drawerName from drawer");
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                    {
                    $id=$row['idDrawer'];
                    $data=$row['drawerName'];
                    echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
                     }
                ?>
            </select>*
        </td>
```

Comment: What i would do is separate your php logic from rhe html and make the drop down logic a php function , then use jquery $.ajax to populate the drop down options by appending to an element...this what you wanting?

Comment: how would i do that? :|

Answer (score 0):

Your question leads to a broad discussion. I would suggest following these references:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0CMTQtnZ0G0

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbQUJdimia4

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVHphoGi5dY